# Nested list hover row

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a nested list, and i want to add style for the rows when they are hovered.
But i don't want to hover the parent "LI". I have random elements inside the "li"s so i can't refer to the child elements, these list elements are groups.

[JsFiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/Bergkamp/75EQb/1/)

Sample HTML:

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <ul>
            <li>
                <ul>
                    <li></li>
                     <li></li>
                     <li></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li>
                <ul>
                    <li></li>
                    <li></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

And the CSS:

```
ul {
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
}
ul li {
    background-color: #EEE;
    padding: 10px;
    border: 1px dashed #AAA;
}
ul li:hover{
    background-color: rgba(140,191,38,0.3);
}
```

Comment: It's not clear what you want to do.  What do you consider to be a 'row'?  Maybe you should change your jsFiddle to have different names for each level and then you can refer clearly to the elements by name and exactly what you want to do with them.

Answer (score 0):

You need to fully specify the innermost `li` in your CSS:

```
ul>li>ul>li>ul>li:hover{
    background-color: rgba(140,191,38,0.3);
}
```

If your innermost `li`s exist at different depths throughout your page, you'll need to specify a class instead.

Answer (score 0):

Set a class for the `<ul>` that you want to have responsive `<li>`.  Check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ULNnJ/)

Answer (score 0):

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <ul>
            <li>
                <ul id='hover'>
                    <li></li>
                     <li></li>
                     <li></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li>
                <ul>
                    <li></li>
                    <li></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>

ul#hover li:hover{
    background-color: rgba(140,191,38,0.3);
}
```